# Como hacer un *ngIf dentro de un *ngFor Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Buenas tardes, estoy aprendiendo Ionic 2, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of lista">
  <ion-card-content >
    <ion-card-title>
     {{ data.description }}

      </ion-card-title>
   <ion-grid >
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>Precio del Servicio:</ion-col> <ion-col col-6>${{ data.price }} </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>Estatus del Pago:</ion-col> <ion-col col-6>{{ data.response }}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>Fecha:</ion-col> <ion-col col-6>{{ data.created_at }}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>Trabajador:</ion-col> <ion-col col-6>{{ data.employee.name }} {{ data.employee.last_name }}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row *ngIf="data.status == 'Pendiente'">
    <ion-col col-6><h3>Acerquese a cualquier punto de pago Efecty y realice su pago con el siguiente Pin:</h3></ion-col> <ion-col col-6><h3>{{ data.transaccion.data.ref_payco }}</h3></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row *ngIf="data.status == 'Pendiente'">
    <ion-col col-12><button ion-button clear large (click)="actualizar(data.ref_epayco)"><h3>Si ya Realizó su pago Haga Click aqui para Actualizar el Estatus del Pago</h3></button></ion-col> 
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Cuando Ejecuto la aplicacion, obtengo el error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.
Si quito el *ngIf me muestra los datos sin problemas pero necesito mostrar un botón en caso de que la variable data.status == 'Pendiente'

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que data es nulo hasta que el servicio devuelva la función callback, debes usar el operador `?` para solucionar tu problema

```
  <ion-row *ngIf="data?.status == 'Pendiente'">
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias, en efecto esto solucionó el error.

Comment: @NesslerCamargo si soluciono tu problema, marca la respuesta como solucionado. Saludos